# how to clean duplicate (parent) nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2017

My input payload would be something like the following:

```
  <ns0:SourceFacilityCode FieldTypeToTranslate="Store">
    <ns0:SourceFacilityCode>CRA</ns0:SourceFacilityCode>
  </ns0:SourceFacilityCode>
  <ns0:Alex FieldTypeToTranslate="Facility">
    <ns0:Alex>CRA</ns0:Alex>
  </ns0:Alex>
  <ns0:Shoes>Red</Shoes>
```

As you can see `SourceFacilityCode` and `Alex` are both unnecessary. In order to deserialize this to a concrete C# object, we would need to transform the input to something like this:

```
    <ns0:SourceFacilityCode>CRA</ns0:SourceFacilityCode>
    <ns0:Alex>CRA</ns0:Alex>
    <ns0:Shoes>Red</nso0:Shoes>
```

**How do I transform this payload to look like that?**

What I've tried:

```
1. simple `string.Replace(a,b)`- but this is too messy and ungeneric
2. trying to load this into an Xml concrete object, but this was too difficult to do with the nested nodes having the same name
3. attempting to transform to json and then to concrete object
```

Comment: What is the full XML? Do you need to work with only `SourceFacilityCode` and `Alex` elements or there are some other duplicate elements too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using LINQ to XML:

First, wrap your example XML into a Root element to make it valid XML which can be parsed by XDocument.Parse:

```
var xml = @"<Root xmlns:ns0=""http://example.org/ns0"">
<ns0:SourceFacilityCode FieldTypeToTranslate=""Store"">
    <ns0:SourceFacilityCode>CRA</ns0:SourceFacilityCode>
  </ns0:SourceFacilityCode>
  <ns0:Alex FieldTypeToTranslate=""Facility"">
    <ns0:Alex>CRA</ns0:Alex>
  </ns0:Alex>
  <ns0:Shoes>Red</ns0:Shoes>
</Root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Then we determine all elements with a single child element that has the same name as the element and that has no child elements:

```
var elementsWithSingleChildHavingSameName = doc.Root.Descendants()
    .Where(e => e.Elements().Count() == 1 
        && e.Elements().First().Name == e.Name 
        && !e.Elements().First().HasElements)
    .ToArray();
```

Last, loop through the found elements removing the child element while transferring the value:

```
foreach (var element in elementsWithSingleChildHavingSameName)
{
    var child = element.Elements().First();
    child.Remove();
    element.Value = child.Value;
}
```

To transform back to a string and remove the Root wrapper:

```
var cleanedUpXml = doc.ToString();
var output = Regex.Replace(cleanedUpXml, @"</?Root.*?>", "");
```

Comment: this is beautiful but how do i convert elementsWithSingleChildHavingSameName to string at the end?

Comment: did you mean to change `foreach (var element in elementsWithSingleChildHavingSameName)` to `foreach (var element in doc)`

Comment: sorry im not understanding how to reconstruct the original payload. ??

Comment: You may use a regex or some other method to remove the Root wrapper again. I added an example to my answer.